# CSS isn't containing dximagetransform slideshow in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I just transferred hosts and am having trouble with the slideshow on my website containing itself in I.E. It shows correctly in Firefox and Chrome and I looked at past questions and I couldn't figure it out... please help! www.cwcgroup.com This is just the main page and CSS

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

    <title>CWC Advisors</title>

    <link href="http://media.margotscafe.com/cwcgroup/images/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" > 

    <link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href="http://media.margotscafe.com/cwcgroup/css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href="http://media.margotscafe.com/cwcgroup/css/grid.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href="http://media.margotscafe.com/cwcgroup/css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href="http://media.margotscafe.com/cwcgroup/css/menu.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href="http://media.margotscafe.com/cwcgroup/css/menu-ie.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href="http://media.margotscafe.com/cwcgroup/css/accordion.css">
    <link type="text/css" href="http://media.margotscafe.com/cwcgroup/css/ui-darkness/jquery-ui.css" rel="Stylesheet" /> 

    <!--[if IE]>
      <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://media.margotscafe.com/cwcgroup/css/menu-ie.css">
      <style type="text/css">
        #banner .ie_shadow {
          display: block;
          position: absolute;
          width: 940px;
          height: 100%;
          top:  -10px;
          left: -15px;
          background: #000;
overflow: auto;
          z-index: -1;
          filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius='15', MakeShadow='true', ShadowOpacity='1');
        }
        #content .ie_shadow.left {
          display: block;
          position: absolute;
          width: 5px;
          height: 100%;
          top:  -10px;
          left: -10px;
          background: #000;
overflow: auto;
          z-index: -1;
          filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius='15', MakeShadow='true', ShadowOpacity='1');
        }
        #content .ie_shadow.right {
          display: block;
          position: absolute;
          width: 5px;
          height: 100%;
          top:  -10px;
          left: 920px;
          background: #000;
overflow: auto;
          z-index: -1;
          filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius='15', MakeShadow='true', ShadowOpacity='1');
        }
        #image_wrapper .ie_shadow.left {
          display: block;
          position: absolute;
          width: 10px;
          height: 550px;
          top: -10px;
          left: -5px;
          background: #000;
overflow: auto;
          z-index: -1;
          filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius='15', MakeShadow='true', ShadowOpacity='1');
        }
        #image_wrapper .ie_shadow.right {
          display: block;
          position: absolute;
          width: 5px;
          height: 550px;
          top: -10px;
          left: 930px;
          background: #000;
overflow: auto;
          z-index: -1;
          filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius='15', MakeShadow='true', ShadowOpacity='1');
        }
      </style>
    <![endif]-->


    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Vollkorn" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href="http://media.margotscafe.com/cwcgroup/css/typography.css">


<style type="text/css" >
#logo {margin-left: -35px}
</style>


  </head>
  <body>
<div class="container_12"><header class="grid_12">
<ul class="topnav prefix_1">
<li><a href="/index">Home</a></li>
<li><a style="cursor: default;">About CWC</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="/our_company">Our Company</a></li>
<li><a href="/our_team">Our Team</a></li>
<li><a href="/our_philosophy">Our Philosophy</a></li>
<li><a href="/our_process">Our Process</a></li>
<li><a href="/representative_clients">Representative Clients</a></li>
<li><a href="http://media.margotscafe.com/cwcgroup/documents/ADV_Part-2_2012.pdf">ADV Part 2</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a style="cursor: default;">For Individual Investors</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="/small_cap_avf">Small Cap Aggressive Value Fund</a></li>
<li><a href="/large_cap_portfolio">Large Cap Portfolio</a></li>
<li><a href="/international_portfolio">International Portfolio</a></li>
<li><a href="/fixed_income_portfolio">Fixed Income Portfolio</a></li>
<li><a href="/balanced_portfolio">Balanced Portfolio</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a style="cursor: default;">For Institutional Investors</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="/small_cap_institutional">Small Cap Institutional</a></li>
<li><a href="/performance">Performance</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a style="cursor: default;">News and Videos</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="/announcements">News Releases</a></li>
<li><a href="/videos">Videos</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="/contact_us">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="clear"></div>
</header>
<div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="content" class="grid_12"><!--[if IE]>
      <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://media.margotscafe.com/cwcgroup/css/menu-ie.css">
      <style type="text/css">
        #banner .ie_shadow {
          display: block;
          position: absolute;
          width: 940px;
          height: 100%;
          top:  -10px;
          left: -15px;
          background: #000;
          z-index: -1;
          filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius='15', MakeShadow='true', ShadowOpacity='1');
        }
        #content .ie_shadow.left {
          display: block;
          position: absolute;
          width: 5px;
          height: 100%;
          top:  -10px;
          left: -10px;
          background: #000;
          z-index: -1;
          filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius='15', MakeShadow='true', ShadowOpacity='1');
        }
        #content .ie_shadow.right {
          display: block;
          position: absolute;
          width: 5px;
          height: 100%;
          top:  -10px;
          left: 870x;
          background: #000;
          z-index: -1;
          filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius='15', MakeShadow='true', ShadowOpacity='1');
        }
        #image_wrapper .ie_shadow.left {
          display: block;
          position: absolute;
          width: 10px;
          height: 550px;
          top: -10px;
          left: 33px;
          background: #000;
          z-index: -1;
          filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius='15', MakeShadow='true', ShadowOpacity='1');
        }
        #image_wrapper .ie_shadow.right {
          display: block;
          position: absolute;
          width: 5px;
          height: 550px;
          top: -10px;
          left: 871px;
          background: #000;
          z-index: -1;
          filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius='15', MakeShadow='true', ShadowOpacity='1');
        }
      </style>
    <![endif]-->
<div id="logo-banner">
<div id="logo"></div>
<ul class="logo-banner-accordion">
<li class="default" id="acc1">
<h3>CWC Advisors launches first mutual fund</h3>
<p>Symbol: CWCRX and CWCIX</p>
</li>
<li id="acc2">
<h3>Thane Cleland</h3>
<p><a href="videos#1">Meet CWC CEO and Chief Investment Officer<br /> Thane Cleland</a></p>
</li>
<li id="acc3">
<h3>Gary Woolworth</h3>
<p><a href="videos#2">Meet CWC President Gary Woolworth.</a></p>
</li>
<li id="acc4">
<h3>Cherrie Prinz</h3>
<p><a href="videos#3">Meet CWC Analyst Cherrie Prinz</a></p>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="image_wrapper">
<div id="images" class="grid_12"><img src="http://media.margotscafe.com/cwcgroup/images/2.jpg" /> <img src="http://media.margotscafe.com/cwcgroup/images/5.jpg" /> <img src="http://media.margotscafe.com/cwcgroup/images/3.jpg" /> <img src="http://media.margotscafe.com/cwcgroup/images/4.jpg" /> <img src="http://media.margotscafe.com/cwcgroup/images/1.jpg" /></div>
<div class="ie_shadow left"></div>
<div class="ie_shadow right"></div>
</div>
<div id="login"><form method="post" action="https://cwcgroup.sharefile.com">Email: <input type="text" name="username" /> Password: <input type="password" name="password" /> <input type="submit" value="Log In" /> <a href="https://cwcgroup.sharefile.com/?cmd=p">Forgot your password?</a></form></div>
</div>
<div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
<footer class="grid_11 prefix_1">
<div class="footer-links grid_4"><a href="/privacy">Privacy Policy</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="/disclosure">Disclosure</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="/gips">GIPS Compliance</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="/admin/">Login</a></div>
<div class="copyright prefix_5" style="margin-left: -10px;">&copy;2011 <a href="http://www.cwcgroup.com">CWC Advisors</a> | <a href="http://www.marlercommunications.com">Web by Marler Communications</a> | <a href="http://www.mirwin.net">Design by Mirwin</a></div>
</footer></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.7/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://media.margotscafe.com/cwcgroup/js/jquery.dropdown.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://media.margotscafe.com/cwcgroup/js/jquery.cycle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://media.margotscafe.com/cwcgroup/js/jquery.pngfix.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://media.margotscafe.com/cwcgroup/js/jquery.kwicks.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).pngFix();

    $('#images').cycle({
      fx: 'fade',
      speed: 2500,
      timeout: 5000 
    });
    $('.logo-banner-accordion').kwicks({
      min: 40,
      spacing: 0,
      sticky: true,
    });

      });
// ]]></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am running I.E. 8 and I have a little exclamation point on the lower left when viewing http://www.cwcadvisors.com/ - clicking this will show you the error message which is:
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Mon, 20 May 2013 17:34:52 UTC

Message: Expected identifier, string or number
Line: 249
Char: 5
Code: 0
URI: http://www.cwcadvisors.com/

Then look at the page source line 249 char 5.  It is the ending }); for the logo-banner-accordion There is something here I.E. does not like. That should get you started, hope this was helpful!

Comment: @NickLong You have a comma at the end of the previous line so IE is expecting another property.

Comment: Yeah I'm getting a couple of problems here and im not quite sure how to fix them :/

Comment: line 248? Is that the line that has the extra comma?

Comment: I made the correction on 248 and its still returning with the slideshow being separated into 4 pictures in IE and overlapping the .css :/ I'm getting 4 issues on dreamweaver: z-index bug on lines 98 and 197; float drop problem on 135 and 225

Comment: Nick - this is the line that has the extra ","     
      sticky: true,
    });      Because there is a comma after true it thinks there should be another parameter coming.

Comment: Try removing the whole " $('.logo-banner-accordion').kwicks({min: 40, spacing: 0,
      sticky: true,
    });  I don't think I.E. likes this Jquery function. P.S. If you want to thank me click the up arrow on my answer.  Best regards -Tom